# How to remove buttons on List View for Community?

Tags: list-view, partner-communities, community, list-button

We don't want to let our community users to use some custom buttons.
Is there a way to hide or remove custom buttons on List View for Community?

Comment: Which button are you referring to, custom or standard. Add some more details to the question.

Comment: We need to hide(remove) custom buttons on List View for Community.

Comment: You can create another list view without the buttons and share with the community users, and the original share only with internal users.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean buttons like "New", to insert a new record, you can just edit the user's profile permissions to not allow him to create new records of that object.

If editing the profile isn't suitable for you, you can go to Setup > Create > Objects > *YourObject* (for Custom Object) and search for *YourObject List View* in the Search Layouts section. When you click Edit, Salesforce will show up a page where you can enable/disable the buttons that appear in list views. I'm not certain, but I believe this would affect **every user in the organization**, regardless of his profile.

Edit: If you are refering to a standard object, you go to Setup > Customize > *Object* > *Object* Search Layouts.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an old question, but a colleague showed me something that might help.

You can isolate the class of each of these buttons, using your browsers inspect feature, and hide them using the display property in your custom CSS.

For example, the '**list view controls**', and '**display as**' buttons are controlled by  `.slds-button_icon-more`. By adding `.slds-button_icon-more{display:none;}` to your custom CSS, the browser will no longer render these two buttons.

Note that the way `{display:none;}` is applied here hides these elements from the entire community. Be sure to thoroughly evaluate that you have no further use for these elements before hiding them. I planned on using the 'New' button in other ways throughout the community, which is why I chose not to hide the 'New' button in the example below.

Before:
[image: List view with buttons.]

After:
[image: List view without buttons]

Hiding the specific button classes with the `{display:none;}` command. 
[image]

Comment: Very "hacky" solution but works so well!

Comment: The only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous comment: it's better to utilize a more specific selector when targeting buttons to hide in css:

[data-target-selection-name="sfdc:CustomButton.Order.your-action-name]{
display:none;
}

You can just use inspect tools in Chrome to find out the value of **data-target-selection-name** property for the button you want to hide.